# T-SQL IntelliSense does not work on some solutions

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, t-sql, intellisense

I have a solution in Visual Studio 2013, where among the others I have also a Database project. This project contains some `.sql` written in T-SQL.

IntelliSence and Parse (SQL (on visual studio menu) > Parse) do not work. I have gone through this [Troubleshooting guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ee362020%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and many question on SO, but nothing worked.

As I understand is something in project setting that I need to configure or some leftovers I need to clean.
Any suggestions ?

In brief

- IntelliSence is enable
- SQL CMD is Disabled
- In SQL Server Explorer there is an entry (localdb)\ProjectsV12 containing my DB.
- Other solutions opened on the same instance of visual studio work fine
- ReSharper is installed but is not the issue (I also tried without it)

Note:

1. The solution (the one that has issues) was created in a previous version of Visual Studio.

**Update 15/12/2015**
After some digging I found out that the issue may has something to do with the `.v12.suo` file (which is located alongside with `.sln` file and is hidden). Copping this file from a similar solution (one that IntelliSence works) eliminates the problem.

Another workaround that it may help, is to go to the "Database Project" properties (right click on the project in  Solution Explorer and then select Properties), on the Debug tab and press `Restore Default` in "Target Connection String". In my case this just changes the `Initial Catalog=` value to `Database` and like "magic" IntelliSence works again! (in some cases it may need to restart the Visual Studio)

After this even if I restore (using Edit) the "Target Connection String" to the previous values the IntelliSence continues to work.